# Construct GET url from java script and submit

Tags: javascript

On click of search button in my form, i want to set some param to url and submit it.

Below is my javascript

```
function validateSubmitSearch(form) {   
  if(form.elements["iAccept"].checked == true) {
    form.query.value=form.search_query.value;
    form.action = "vendor/search";
    form.method = "GET";
    form.submit();
  }
}
```

This javascript is returning url as
    http://localhost:8080/Project/vendor/search?query=xxx&search_query=xxx&search=Search

Instead i need it as
    http://localhost:8080/Project/vendor/search?query=xxx

How this can be done ?

EDIT:

I cannot remove form elements `search_query` and `search`

Here is HTML code

```
<form class="searchform" onSubmit="validateSubmitSearch(this)">
  <input name="query" type="hidden" />
  <input name="search_query" class="textbox" type="text" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="iAccept" name="iAccept" value="I ACCEPT">
  <input name="search" class="button" value="Search" type="submit" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: please add complate of your html codes .

Comment: what is the value of `form.search_query.value;`?

Comment: @IvanBarayev : Added HTML code

Comment: @SamuelToh : form.search_query.value = input text in textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form with `method="GET", all the input fields in the form will be included as URL parameters. If you want some of them to be left out, you need to remove those inputs from the form.

```
function validateSubmitSearch(form){

    if(form.elements["iAccept"].checked == true)
        {
            form.query.value=form.search_query.value;
            form.action = "vendor/search";
            form.method = "GET";
            form.seach_query.parentNode.removeChild(form.search_query);
            form.search.parentNode.removeChild(form.search);
            form.submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should disable the default form submission by returning `false` from the `onsubmit` code.

```
<form class="searchform" onsubmit="validateSubmitSearch(this); return false;">
```

Comment: This is not working either, URL still has the unwanted params

Comment: How are you calling the function? Maybe you're not disabling the default submission.

Comment: Thanks mate, You hit the bulls eye.